# If $\int_a^bg(x)dx=0$, show that $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

Let $g(x)\ge0$. If $\int_a^bg(x)dx=0$, show that $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx=0,$ where $f$ is any integrable function.

If simeone is allowed to use the Mean Value thorem for integrals, the proof is at hand. But for that $f$ must be continuous!

Any suggestion?

Comment: Just show that $g$ is identically zero.

Comment: Isn't $g$ identically zero on the interval $[a,b]$ to make this true? How else can the integral of a non-negative function be zero?

Comment: If $g \ge 0$ and $\int ^b_a g(x) dx = 0$ then $g = 0$ almost everywhere, and so $fg =0$ almost everywhere as well.

Comment: @Artem it isn't, necessarily

Comment: @qbert, how so? this isn't a Lebesgue integral. the OP tagged "riemann-integration".

Comment: @TheCount it doesn't matter, the Riemann integral still doesn't see sets of measure $0$

Comment: @qbert Ooof, I've been teaching introductory calculus too long. Silly me. Forgot.

Comment: @TheCount no sweat, I generally distrust the Riemann-integral myself :P

Comment: @qbert as we all should!

Comment: @qbert The Riemann integral sort of does see sets of measure zero, it's just that it doesn't see them when distinguishing between Riemann integrable functions. It does see them when distinguishing between a Riemann integrable function $f$ and a non-Riemann-integrable function a.e. equal to $f$ (e.g. $0$ and $1_{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]}$).

Comment: @Ian that's a fair and nuanced point I hadn't thought of in this context. Thank you for sharing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I try to prove this without invoking anything about Lebesgue integral. Moreover, I do not assume the fact that $fg$ is Riemann integrable nor the inequality $| \int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx | \leq \int_a^b |f(x)g(x)|dx$.

$f$ is Riemann integrable $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is bounded. Choose
$M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Let $\varepsilon>0$
be given. Choose $\delta>0$ such that for any partition $\mathbb{P}=\{x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\}$
of $[a,b]$ (with $a=x_{0}<x_{1}<\ldots<x_{n}=b$) and any $\xi_{i}\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$,
if $||\mathbb{P}||<\delta$ (here, $||\mathbb{P}||=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|x_{i}-x_{i-1}|$),
then 
$$
\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(\xi_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})-\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{M}.
$$
That is, 
$$
\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(\xi_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{M}.
$$

Now, let $\mathbb{P}=\{x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\}$ be an arbitrary
partition of $[a,b]$, with $a=x_{0}<x_{1}<\ldots<x_{n}=b$, that
satisfies $||\mathbb{P}||<\delta$. Let $\xi_{i}\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$
be arbitrary. Then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\xi_{i})g(\xi_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})-0\right|\\
 & \leq & \sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(\xi_{i})g(\xi_{i})|(x_{i}-x_{i-1})\\
 & \leq & M\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(\xi_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})\\
 & < & M\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{M}\\
 & = & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that the Riemann integral $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx$ exists
and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx=0$.

Comment: Props for a complete answer that doesn't invoke the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @Alex Ortiz Although it is true that if $f$ and $g$ are Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$, then $fg$ is also Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, this fact is not an axiom and it requires a proof. I tried to assume as less as possible and avoid invoking this fact.

Answer (score 6):

This is about Riemann integration, so $f,g$ are necessarily bounded.

We'll use that.

$$\int_a^b f g dx =\int_a^b \underset{\mbox{nonnegative}}{\underbrace{(f - \inf f)}} g dx+ (\inf f )\underset{=0}{\underbrace{\int_a^b  g dx}} $$

so the problem is reduced to Riemann integrable nonnegative $f$. For such $f$

$$ 0\le \int_a^b g f dx \le (\sup f) \int_a^b g dx =0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $g(x)\ge0$ and $\int_{a}^bg(x)=0$, then for every $\epsilon>0$, $m(\{x:g(x)\ge\epsilon\})=0$ where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^1$. Set $\int_a^b |f(x)|dx=M<\infty$ since $f(x)$ is integrable.
\begin{align}
\int_a^b |f(x)g(x)|dx&=\int_a^b |f(x)|g(x) \chi_{\{x:g(x)<\epsilon\}}dx+\int_a^b |f(x)|g(x)\chi_{\{x:g(x)\ge \epsilon\}}dx\\
&\le \epsilon\int_a^b |f(x)|dx\\
&=\epsilon M
\end{align}
Since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrary small, we conclude that $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx=0$.

---

Or you may use the idea above to prove that $g(x)=0$ a.e. To do this, note that we can decompose the set $\{x:g(x)>0\}$ as

> $$\displaystyle{\{x:g(x)>0\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{ x: g(x)\ge\frac 1n \}}$$

and note that

> $$ m(\{x:g(x)>0\})\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(\{ x: g(x)\ge\frac 1n \})=0 .$$

We can conclude that $g(x)=0$ a.e. This will give you $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=0.$

Comment: It seems that OP prohibits the use of anything related to Lebesgue integral. If we are allowed to do so, then it is one line. $f\geq 0$ and $\int f=0$ implied that $f=0$ a.e.. Then $fg=0$ a.e., so $\int fg=0$.

Comment: But you need to prove that $f\ge 0$ and $\int f=0$ implies $f=0$ a.e. :)

Comment: This is an obviously fact. Let $A=\{x\mid f(x)>0\}$. Then $A=\cup_{n=1}^\infty \{x\mid f(x)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$. If $\mu(A)>0$, then $\mu(A_n)>0$ for some $n$. Then $\int f \geq \int_{A_n} f \geq \frac{1}{n}\mu(A_n)>0$. Here, $A_n =\{x\mid f(x)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Well, basically the same thing as I mentioned in the latter part of my post...

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$
\begin{align}
p_n(x)
&=\frac{|x-n|-|x-n-1|-|x+n|+|x+n+1|}2\\[6pt]
&=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
-1&\text{if }x\lt-n-1\\
x+n&\text{if }-n-1\le x\lt-n\\
0&\text{if }-n\le x\lt n\\
x-n&\text{if }n\le x\lt n+1\\
1&\text{if }n+1\le x
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
$$
In particular, $p_n$ is continuous, so that $p_n(f)$ is integrable. Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p_k(x)
&=\frac{|x+n|-|x-n|}2\\
&=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
-n&\text{if }x\lt-n\\
x&\text{if }-n\le x\lt n\\
n&\text{if }n\le x\\
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\int_a^bf(x)\,g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|
&=\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_a^bp_n(f(x))\,g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\\
&\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_a^b|p_n(f(x))|\,g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_a^b\,g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty0\\[6pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Note that if $f$ is finite, then the sum above is finite.

Comment: One should try to avoid using anything about Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Actually the OP didn't say that...

Comment: Implicitly in the tag... I agree that OP should state this explicitly.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with Lebesgue integration, and I have modified the answer to make that more apparent.

Comment: I didn't check that the convergence $\sum_1^N p_n(f)\to_N f$ is uniform, so that you know it is valid to change integral and summation. May be worth mentioning.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz: if $f$ is Riemann integrable, then $f$ is finite, then the sum is finite. It is valid to interchange a finite sum and integration.